# How to Serialize Java Object into json and Reverse Json to Object when using springboot with Redis?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, redis

I am using SpringBoot with Redis And want to serial object UserDO into Json, store it in Redis, and get the json data, reverse it into UserDO Object.
This is UserDO

```
public class UserDO {
String name;
int age;
String password;

// Getters and Setters are not here
```

}
This is how I set the Serializer:

```
@Configuration
```

public class RedisTemplateConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {

    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);

    // 使用Jackson2JsonRedisSerialize 替换默认序列化
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    // 设置key和value的序列化规则
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

    // 设置hashKey和hashValue的序列化规则
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

    // 设置支持事物
    //redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);

    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

    return redisTemplate;
}
```

}

It works when I use `redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("user-service:user:2",userDO);`

But when I Run `uo = (UserDO)redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("user-service:user:2")`
I got a LinkedHashMap

```
@Test
void testSeriable(){
    User user = new User();
    user.setAge(18);
    user.setName("William");
    user.setPwd("testpwd");
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("user:2", user);

    System.out.println(redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("user:2").getClass());
    Map<String, String> res = ((LinkedHashMap<String, String>)redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("user:2"));
    System.out.println(res);
    /*
    class java.util.LinkedHashMap
    {name=William, age=18, pwd=testpwd}
     */

    redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPushAll("testkey", user, user, user);
    List<User> list = redisTemplate.opsForList().range("testkey", 0, -1);
    System.out.println(list);
    /*
    This works fine!
    [{name=William, age=18, pwd=testpwd}, {name=William, age=18, pwd=testpwd}, {name=William, age=18, pwd=testpwd}]
     */
}
```

So How can I get User directly from redisTemplate.opsForList().get() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want your template typed to a specific type of key and model, something like:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Person> redisTemplate() {
  RedisTemplate<String, User> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
  redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
  redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
  
  Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL,  JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
  jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

  redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
  redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

  redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
  redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

  return redisTemplate;
}
```

You'll need a Primary Key for your DTO object so that SDR can use it to construct a key. It'll be the fully qualified class name by default + ":" + your PK.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a generic methods to serialize data and deserialize data using a particular class object

For this i am using

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
```

you can add it in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and in your Redis impl class you add these two methods

```
public final static String INVALID_SERIALIZATION_OR_DESERIALIZATION = "Invalid type passed for marshalling";

public String serializeData(T modelClass)
        throws SerializationOrDeserializationException {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(modelClass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("{}", e);
        throw new SerializationOrDeserializationException(INVALID_SERIALIZATION_OR_DESERIALIZATION);
    }
}

public T deserializeData(String value, Class<T> type) {
    try {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return objectMapper.readValue(value, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("{}", e);
        throw new SerializationOrDeserializationException(INVALID_SERIALIZATION_OR_DESERIALIZATION);
    }
}
```

And in you can create a custom exeception

```
public class SerializationOrDeserializationException extends RuntimeException {
    public SerializationOrDeserializationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Then you can use serialize desrialize in following fashion

```
className.deserializeData('json_sring',User.class);
className.serializeData(userObject);
```